# Populate CheckboxSelectMultiple with existing data from django model form

Tags: django, django-forms

hoping someone can help shed some light on this for me.  Im working on a notifications app where users can register to recieve emails when blog posts are submitted for specific categories IE i only want emails for the cat's media and buying for example

i have a basic model defined as

## model

```
class BlogNotifications(models.Model):
    
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    sites = models.ManyToManyField(Site)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Categories)
    objects = models.Manager()
    
    def __unicode__ (self):

    return self.user.username
```

basically the form should only out the categories which is the many to many field categories defined in the model above.  The form looks like

## modelform

```
class BlogNotificationsForm(forms.ModelForm):
            
    class Meta:
        model = BlogNotifications
        exclude = ('user', 'sites',)
        widgets = {
            'categories': forms.widgets.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
        }
```

the form is rendering the many to many field as Check boxes correctly but what im wondering is how to go about populating those check boxes with existing data, ie the user has already opted in to receive blog emails about media, buying and planning those check boxes should appear checked when the user navigates back to the page.

I have tried defining the queryset option on the ModelForm but that didn't seem to do anything for me.. Any help is greatly appreciated

Cheers

Comment: anyone got any ideas on this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When instantiating the `modelForm` I wasn't passing the instance of `BlogNotifications` model to it.  So in the view the form set up looks like:

```
blogForm = BlogNotificationsForm(instance=BlogNotifications.objects.get(user=request.user))
```

I hope this may help someone in the future, it really wasn't that clear in the docs to me!!

Comment: I have the same problem and I followed your steps but I am getting the data using reverse queries like ```request.user.ModelName_set.all()``` It is throwing error  saying ```no _Meta field present``` . Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please [take a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57884248/render-a-checkboxselectmultiple-form-using-the-data-present-in-database-initia)

Answer (score 1):

In the view maybe you can set the queryset like this:

```
form = BlogNotificationsForm()
form.fields["categories"].queryset = Categories.objects.all()
```

I found this example [here](http://www.wkoorts.com/wkblog/2009/08/10/pre-populate-django-modelform-with-specific-queryset/)

Comment: Hey thanks for you answer, This is along the lines of what i already tried, however this wont work for my use case as if i filter by lets say user on the form fields, that will remove the categories the user hasnt already set if that makes sense, what i need i think is to render the form a manually check the boxes for the categories the user had already selected by grabbing the objects out of the database, this seems rather silly that it dosent automatically populate the form in this way.  Im still searching so hopefully i can find the answer somewhere!!

Comment: I have the same problem. Can you please [take a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57884248/render-a-checkboxselectmultiple-form-using-the-data-present-in-database-initia)