# Render a CheckBoxSelectMultiple form using the data present in Database. [initial value is a queryset from DB]

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a form called `DemoForm` which is related to model `Demo`

```
class Demo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ans = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
```

and the form for this is

```
class DemoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Demo
        exclude = ('user',)
        widgets = {'ans': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple}
```

I want to render this form using a `queryset` I have tried  different approaches like

```
form = DemoForm(initial=Love.objects.filter(user=request.user))


<form=GoodForm()  
form.fields["ans"].queryset = Love.objects.filter(user=request.user) >


form=DemoForm(instance=Love.objects.filter(user=request.user)


form=DemoForm(instance=request.user.love_set.all())
```

Sometimes it is showing `no _Meta present` and when I use initial, it shows the `expected  length 2 got 1 (got 3)`

**NOTE- The `Love` model is related to user in the same way as the `Demo` is related to user using `ForeignKey`. Means the `Love` model is a copy of `Demo` model. So the query returns nested objects**

Comment: Instead of customizing the widget you can try the ModelMultipleChoiceField:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField
That could do the trick for you :)

Comment: and how can I pre-populate it? DO I have to convert it to list or the current query is okay?

Comment: @Wolph and how'd I query it? My implementation requires ```request```.

Comment: You can simply pass a queryset. If you need it to change depending on the request you need to override the `__init__` method of the form to change the queryset on the fly

Comment: can You please [take a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57895082/how-to-render-a-checkboxselectmultiple-form-using-forms-modeform-that-uses-data)? This the thing I implemented. But there's a new problem associated with it.

Comment: Charfield is saved in DB. I want to render the char fields as the options.

Answer (score 0):

You can populate the charfield data with multiselect checkbox by using `MultipleChoiceField` with `CheckboxSelectMultiple` widget, and override choice field in **init** mwthod as per the requirement.

```
class DemoForm(ModelForm):
   ans = MultipleChoiceField(widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple)

class Meta:
    model = Demo
    exclude = ('user',)

def __init__(self, *args, user=None, **kwargs):
    super(DemoForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    if user:
        # Assuming Love model has a CharField named 'ans'
        love_objects = Love.objects.filter(user=user)
        choices = [(obj.ans, obj.ans) for obj in love_objects]
        self.fields['ans'].choices = choices
```

And you can simple use the form in your views.py, For FBV

```
def demo_form_view(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
       form = DemoForm(request.POST, user=request.user)
       if form.is_valid():
           # Do something with the valid form data
           # For example, save the form
   else:
       form = DemoForm(user=request.user)

   return render(request, 'demo_form.html', {'form': form})
```